# Find a conformal map from $\mathbb{D}=\{z;0<\operatorname{arg} z<2π\}$ to $Ω=\{w;0<\operatorname{Im} w<π\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a conformal map from $\mathbb{D}=\{z;0<\operatorname{arg} z<2π\}$ to $Ω=\{w;0<\operatorname{Im} w<π\}$.

I am having difficulty with this question.  Some help would be awesome.  Thanks

Comment: this is a slit plane to a horizontal strip, you just compose the exponential to get to a half-plane with a power map to expand the argument.

Er, I guess inverses, but same idea.

Comment: Take the square root.

Comment: And then the log.

Answer (score 1):

The usual conformal map $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{H}$ is given by $z \mapsto z^{1/2}$, and a conformal map $\mathbb{H} \to \Omega$ is given by $w \to \log(w)$, where here $\log$ is the branch of the complex logarithm obtained by deleting the negative imaginary axis. Composing the two, we get the map $f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ given by
$$
f(z) = \log\left( z^{1/2} \right).
$$
The full details on the two maps can be found in Chapter 8.1 of Stein and Shakarchi's "Complex Analysis" book.

Comment: What the OP writes as $\mathbb D$ is not the unit disc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - should be ok now.

Comment: Well, note that OP is deleting the positive real axis - you might want to be doing $\sqrt{-z}$, which will then give you the right-half plane (or at least specify what branch of $\sqrt$ you're using).